# How do I stop my Player from attaching to my mouse? (Unity 2D)

Tags: c, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game where you can teleport to the Mouse position when you press "Q". When I load in the game to play the player essentialy gets attached to the mouse (Where the mouse moves the player also moves) Whenever I press Q again it detaches. After that it works as intended(teleports to the mouse position when I press Q). I've tried different Keys and also tried mouse button.
My code:

```
private void Update()
    {
        MousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
            hit = Physics2D.BoxCast(MousePos, coll.bounds.size, 0f, Vector2.zero, 3f);
            if (hit == false)
                if (teleportUses > 0)
                    transform.position = MousePos;
                else return;
}
```

Comment: I think perhaps the Keycode Q check should have curly brackets after it, so that both where "hit" gets a value and where you check if it has a value are within the same bracket. Because otherwise "hit" will have no value until you have pressed Q at least once. Either that or you should set a default value for hit where it's false. Might work.

Answer (score -1):

Without curly braces `{ }` the `if` condition is only applied to the next statement. So your code basically equals

```
MousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
{
    hit = Physics2D.BoxCast(MousePos, coll.bounds.size, 0f, Vector2.zero, 3f);
}

if (!hit)
{
    if (teleportUses > 0)
    {
        transform.position = MousePos;
    }
    else 
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

So I guess the issue is that at the beginning `hit == false` is always the case and you probably rather wanted

```
MousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
{
    hit = Physics2D.BoxCast(MousePos, coll.bounds.size, 0f, Vector2.zero, 3f);

    if (!hit)
    {
        if (teleportUses > 0)
        {
            transform.position = MousePos;
        }
        else 
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I greatly appreciate it!